# Swift 3: UITableViewCell disable selection style also disables selection

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have a serious issue with my `tableview` cell. So here is the scenario:

1. Enter edit mode within the table view
2. Indent checkmarks come in and I like to select the cells by tapping them
   without having the blue/grey/whatever selection style.

**What did I do:**

*TableView*:

```
self.tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = true
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
```

*Cell*:

```
self.selectionStyle = .none -> Results in no longer selectable cells
```

**Expectation:**

Checkmark on the left gets selected without having the damn blue border/grey background.

**Result:**

Backgroundview is visible which kills the cells subviews (blue background disappears, white text no longer visible, etc.)

*What I already tested without any positive result:*

```
Cell.appearence().selectedBackground.color = UIColor.clear
```

or

```
cell.selectedBackground.color = UIColor.clear
```

or

```
override var isSelected:... within the cell
```

Maybe you have any ideas.

Comment: Change the selection style from the Attribute Inspector

Comment: to avoid selection while tapping the cell -> func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { cell.selectionStyle = .none return cell }

Comment: Your question is bit unclear. You don't want selection color to be displayed which you know can be achieved by setting this property in cell `self.selectionStyle = .none` so whats the problem ?

Comment: I try to clarify it a little: I don't want the selection color, therefore i set selectionStyle to .none. BUT this leads to the issue that i can tap on the cell but the indented checkmark on the left doesn't get the check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with my own custom solution to the described problem:

within the awakeFromNib method of the cell i just created UIView instance like:

```
self.selectedBackgroundView = UIView()
```

without doing any more in that method. As an addition to solve my problem, i outsourced all of my ui design stuff to a custom method.

Then i overwrote the ***setHighlighted*** and ***setSelected*** methods:

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    self.setUIproperties()
}

override func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setHighlighted(highlighted, animated: animated)
    self.setUIproperties()
}
```

***Why did i do this?***

Cause overwriting is necessary to provide the custom design for your cell. Otherwise all of the backgrounds would've been set to white.
*Overwriting setSelected isn't enough*, cause when you long press the cell, it will blink and you see, that the highlighted state will also manipulate your ui.

I hope this helps to some of you.

Comment: I have same problem. Could you please describe what are you doing in `self.setUIproperties()` method?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    //...
}
```

Comment: User will still see the gray / blue selection blink when they tap the cell. Plus, user will still see the gray / blue background if they long press.